# Passing Map from JSP to Action Class in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

How I can pass a Map from JSP to my Action?
Here the JSP:

```
        <logic:iterate id="mbMap" name="sammelmeldungEmpfaegerZuweisungForm" property="mandantenauswhal">
         <tr>
        <td class="FieldValueTD" width="400">
        <html:checkbox name="mbMap" property="value"/>
        <bean:define id="mandant" name="mbMap" property="key"/>
        <bean:write name="mandant" property="name"/>
        </td></tr>
        </logic:iterate>
```

And here the Action were I put the values in:

```
        form.setSpkId(spkId); // int
    form.setMandantenauswhal(mb); // HashMap
    form.setSammelmeldungdefinitionId(smId.intValue()); // int
```

In the next step I want to read the values entred by user, but the HashMap in the form ist empty! The "spkId" and "sammelmeldungdefinitionId" are filled whit values. 
Here my Debug view:
[image]
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: really no one ?

Comment: tech stack is really old. I forgot the struts :)